# How to backup drivers?

Tags: backup

I just wanted to know if there any very easy way to backup and restore drivers just like  system restore in Windows system? I don't  want to revert back to original factory settings state. Just wanted to roll back to old drivers if anything goes wrong while installing new one or updating. (I am really missing system restore feature of Windows)

Answer (score 2):

You are showing that you are new ;-) Regarding your concerns:

- All you need to worry about backing up is your private data. You can copy those files over to a media to create a backup or setup our backup tool `deja-dup` to create automatic backups.
- If you use server software on your machine (like `apache` or `mysql`) you also might consider backing up the config files for those.

For all other software, we have the official repositories. So why waste a DVD, USB stick or hard disc space to keep a copy that is available online or even on your installation media.

In Ubuntu, we have the additional drivers tab that holds all the drivers you ever need to take care of. Why do you need a backup if they are on the servers from Canonical? I can not think of a better place for them to be saved for me.

> I don't want to revert back to original factory settings state

Why is that a worry to you? The additional drivers tab holds both the original and proprietary driver and maybe a 3rd one. It might also hold a wireless driver. And that is it. It is always there for you if you want to switch graphics cards.

1 thing of advice for you: forget about how you do things in Windows. Linux does things in another way. That does not mean either way is wrong (just that the 2 operating systems came from different perspectives (Windows single user; Linux multi-user) and have had other thoughts about how to do things.

I hope I took away a lot (if not all) of your concerns. Join us in chat (20+ rep required ;) ) if you have questions. Happy Ubunting.

Comment: Thanks for such quick reply. I asked this question cause I faced a problem just today. After updating the software last night, I was unable to connect to internet (it was showing "no wireless devices" and when I plugged ethernet cable it was not detecting either). I didn't changed any setup, It was all working fine before the update. I tried to find solution but since I am very new to ubuntu I could not roll back to old drivers. I panicked and used the recovery disk to revert back to factory setting. And it is working fine now. I am afraid to use the software updater again.

Comment: that probably is not a driver issue but a command you might need to start (something like ifup ;) ) Drivers are not the 1st thing I think about when hearing this (drivers are never my 1st thought: they are an issue during install and 1st testing if all works; never when everything did work at some point ;)

Comment: Ok. I am running the software updater again lets see what happens. will post in here if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Update finished. But this time its working fine :) Can you tell me where to find guide to setup ubuntu for first time user? like all the basic softwares and settings to be done?

Comment: There is no guide for that since it is 100% personal (after install I set up trim for my ssd, install shutter and smplayer and that's it ;) )

Comment: For some strange reason now wired connection is not showing. the result of "sudo lshw -C network" showing ethernet controller under *-network unclaimed. pls help

Comment: @Sourav feel free to create a new topic about that (after checking if it has not been asked before ;) )

Comment: created a topic. it was fine after last recovery but today not showing the wired connection under system :( can you guide me please.

Answer (score 2):

> Just wanted to roll back to old drivers if anything goes wrong while installing new one or updating

Please, don't! Linux has the peculiarity that **all drivers are built-in the kernel**, loaded if needed, and such modules (is how Linux calls drivers) are built specifically for each version of the kernel, and won't work on others. These modules are included in all installations of Ubuntu by default. If your system worked just fine, is highly likely it will work fine in a new installation. The only preoccupation may be that there's a regression in the modules, but these are weird and easily solvable.

> if there any very easy way to backup and restore drivers just like system restore in Windows system?

No, not at all. The reasons are explained above.